# Почему не корректно считается координата Y?

Tags: javascript, геометрия

При построении треугольника (равностороннего) по формуле:

```
const xC = (b*b + a*a - c*c) / (2 * a);
const yC = Math.sqrt(b*b - xC*xC);
```

координата `Y`(`yC`) считается не корректно.

Например:
Стороны равны 60, следовательно точка `xC, yC` должна должна иметь координаты `30, 60`, а получается  `30, 51.96152422706632`.

Как решить данную проблему?

```js
const WS_HEIGHT = 300;
  
function check(a,b,c){
  if (a > b+c) return false;
  if (b > a+c) return false;
  if (c > b+a) return false;
  return true;
}

function invertY (val) {
  return WS_HEIGHT - val;
}

function draw(){
  const a = $('input[name="a"]').val();
  const b = $('input[name="b"]').val();
  const c = $('input[name="c"]').val();
  
  if(!check(+a,+b,+c)) {
    alert('Сторона не может быть больше суммы двух других!');
    return;
  }
  
  const xC = (b*b + a*a - c*c) / (2 * a);
  const yC = Math.sqrt(b*b - xC*xC);
  
  console.log('xC:',xC);
  console.log('yC:',yC);

  ac.setAttribute('x1', 0);
  ac.setAttribute('y1', invertY(0));
  ac.setAttribute('x2', a);
  ac.setAttribute('y2', invertY(0));

  ab.setAttribute('x1', 0);
  ab.setAttribute('y1', invertY(0));
  ab.setAttribute('x2', xC);
  ab.setAttribute('y2', invertY(yC));

  bc.setAttribute('x1', a);
  bc.setAttribute('y1', invertY(0));
  bc.setAttribute('x2', xC);
  bc.setAttribute('y2', invertY(yC));
}

$('.submit').on('click', () => draw());
```

```css
.submit{
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  user-select:none;
}
.submit:active{
  background-color:lightgrey;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>a: <input value="60" type="text" name="a"></label><br>
  <label>b: <input value="60" type="text" name="b"></label><br>
  <label>c: <input value="60" type="text" name="c"></label><br>
</div>
<div class="submit">Нарисовать</div>

<svg id="svg" width="300" height="300">
  <line id="ac" x1="0" y1="100" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="red" />
  <line id="ab" x1="0" y1="100" x2="50" y2="0" stroke="red" />
  <line id="bc" x1="50" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Вопрос построен на грубейше некорректной посылке, вроде "Почему у меня 2+2 дает 4, когда должно давать 5".

Comment: @AnT вы правы, но у меня есть большие пробелы в базовой геометрии отсюда такие вопросы. После ответа разобрался и понял, что вопрос странный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> должна должна иметь координаты 30, 60

Не должна. Высота равностороннего треугольника

```
сторона * sqrt(3) / 2
```

Comment: Ок. А что ж тогда за треугольник 60 на 60 на 60? У которого и угол ещё 60 градусов.

Comment: @doox911 Не понял вопроса. Это и есть равносторонний треугольник.

Comment: Спасибо.Разобрался)